# Convert day of the week and time from UTC to ITC in JAVA

Tags: java, java.util.date

In my applications in Db we have fields for Day of the week and time in UTC. So I am trying to display according to server timezone which is IST. I googled it but we should have date for that to convert.Can anyone please help me to solve this issue .

Ex: Sunday 03:00 AM

Thanks

Comment: Please add the piece of code you tried to write and we'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to convert from one timestamp to another

```
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    // Set the formatter to use a different timezone
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
```

Comment: The problem is I do not have Date in Db. I have only day of the week and time like Ex: Sunday 03:00 AM

Comment: it works to:  DateFormat formatter = time; // your time from the DB     than set Timezone and convert like in the snippet